# Call an arbitrary child attribute from a parent class?

Tags: python, oop

I want to 'mark' attributes of a derived class (which are otherwise identical) so that a method of the parent class can use a specific one.

In this example I am building models of neurons, each neuron consists of "regions" which in turn consist of "segments". There is a neuron_region parent class.  The neuron_region parent class has a "connect" method which connects a segment to another segment (passed to it as an argument - on another neuron). There needs to be a way of marking which segment in the derived class needs to be connected to. What is an elegant way to do this?

```
class neuron_region(object):
    def connect(external_segment)
       #connect segment 1 or segment 2 to external_segment, 
       #depending on which one is the right attribute

class child1(parent):
    #mark segment 1 as the segment to which to connect#
    self.seg1='segment 1'
    self.seg2='segment 2'

class child2(parent):
    self.seg1='segment 1'
    #mark segment 2 as the segment to which to connect#
    self.seg2='segment 2'
```

Comment: I have a really hard time understanding what you want to do! :(

Comment: @Deniz - I've improved the code a bit to make it more clear, comments are what I "want" to be able to do. Basically each derived class will have many segments, but only one of them should act as the one which other segments connect to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do The Simplest Thing That Could Possibly Work - maybe something along the lines of:

```
SEGMENTS = (SEGMENT_1, SEGMENT_2) = range(2)

class NeuronRegion(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = [None, None]
        self.chosen = 0
    def choose(self, segment):
        assert segment in SEGMENTS
        self.chosen = segment
    def connect(other_neuron_region):
       # remember to reset those to None when they're not needed anymore, 
       # to avoid cycles that prevent the garbage collector from doing his job:
       self.connection[self.chosen] = other_neuron_region
       other_neuron_region.connection[other_neuron_region.chosen] = self

class Child1(NeuronRegion):
   ''' other stuff '''

class Child2(NeuronRegion):
   ''' other stuff '''
```

**[EDIT]**
I have to admit that I don't like this very much, but it does what you asked for, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
class neuron_region(object):
    def connect(external_segment)
       #connect segment 1 or segment 2 to external_segment, 
       #depending on which one is the right attribute
    # the following can/must be omitted if we don't use the conn_attr approach
    @property
    def connected(self):
        return getattr(self, self.conn_attr)

class child1(parent):
    seg1 = 'segment 1'
    seg2 = 'segment 2'
    #mark segment 1 as the segment to which to connect#
    conn_attr = 'seg1'
    # or directly - won't work if seg1 is changed sometimes...
    connected = seg1


class child2(parent):
    seg1 = 'segment 1'
    seg2 = 'segment 2'
    #mark segment 2 as the segment to which to connect#
    conn_attr = 'seg2'
    # or directly - won't work if seg2 is changed sometimes...
    connected = seg2
```

Here you have even 2 approaches:

1. The child class defines a `conn_attr` attribute to determine which attribute is the one to use for connecting. It is used in the `connected` property in the base class. If `seg1` resp. `seg2` changes from time to time, this is the way to go.
2. The child class directly defines `connected`. Thus, no need for a redirecting property, but that works only if none of the used attributes changes.

In both approaches, the parent class just uses `self.connected`.